# Opengts docker image - mysql Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, docker, opengts

I'm on windows, using linux containers. I'm trying to experiment with `opengts-devel` docker image from docker hub. If I 
follow instructions from the it's page I get MySQL related errors

```
/usr/local/java/bin/java -Xmx300m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath '/usr/local/gts/build/lib/gtsdb.jar:/usr/local/gts/build/lib/gtsutils.jar:/usr/local/gts/build/lib/dmtpserv.jar' org.opengts.db.DBConfig -conf=/usr/local/gts/default.conf -log.file.enable=false -initTables -rootPass=
Version: 2.6.5
[WARN_|DBConnection.parseCommunicationsException:290] SQL(CommunicationsException) close/retry [0]: Connection Age 0 ms
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:1006] SQLException message: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:1007] ==> SQLException: DB create error [jdbc:mysql://:3306/]
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:1007] Message:   Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:1007] SQLState:  08S01
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:1007] ErrorCode: 0
[DBAdmin.execCommands:1007] com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2186)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2219)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2014)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.getConnection(DBConnection.java:809)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.createStatement(DBConnection.java:945)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.createStatement(DBConnection.java:933)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection._executeUpdate(DBConnection.java:1188)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.executeUpdate(DBConnection.java:1161)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.executeUpdate(DBConnection.java:1124)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBProvider.createDatabase(DBProvider.java:1702)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBAdmin.execCommands(DBAdmin.java:995)
        at org.opengts.db.DBConfig._main(DBConfig.java:2030)
        at org.opengts.db.DBConfig.main(DBConfig.java:2174)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
        ... 24 more
Version: 2.6.5
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:1058] ==> SQLException: Connection error [jdbc:mysql://:3306/gts?characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=true&characterSetResults=utf8]
```

This seems to be a single container image containing MySQL as well as web app. Is there something is need change to get it working?

Comment: Hmm is mysql setup to accept remote connections? Per default mysql only listens on `localhost` therefore only accepting connection from the mysql container and denying connections from the other container. Do you have any logs regarding mysql?

Comment: web app and mysql is on the same instance